# Software Updater. The package system is broken. 14.04

Tags: 14.04

error message :

```
Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a  common source of problems.
Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f
```

So i run :

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

it give me this :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  cups cups-bsd cups-client cups-common cups-core-drivers cups-daemon
  cups-server-common libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc6-dbg libc6-dev libcups2
  libcupscgi1 libcupsimage2 libcupsmime1 libcupsppdc1
Suggested packages:
  cups-pdf xpp glibc-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libc-bin
The following packages will be upgraded:
  cups cups-bsd cups-client cups-common cups-core-drivers cups-daemon
  cups-server-common libc-dev-bin libc6-dbg libc6-dev libcups2 libcupscgi1
  libcupsimage2 libcupsmime1 libcupsppdc1
15 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 112 not upgraded.  
Need to get 0 B/8,246 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,509 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
```

I choose Y,and get this :

```
Can't exec "locale": No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl5/Debcon/Encoding.pm line 16.
Use of uninitialized value $Debconf::Encoding::charmap in scalar chomp at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 17.Can't exec "locale": No such file or directory at  /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 16.
Use of uninitialized value $Debconf::Encoding::charmap in scalar chomp at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 17.
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
N: Ignoring file 'ia32-libs-raring.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'steam.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'ia32-libs-raring.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'steam.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)

Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
N: Ignoring file 'ia32-libs-raring.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'steam.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'ia32-libs-raring.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'steam.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

what do i need to do ?

Comment: Try doing the first thing first. "Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them" What I take this to mean is to remove third party entries in the sources that are not working as opposed to renaming them.

Comment: How do disable third party repositories?

Comment: You can edit the list: See http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Trusty_Packages_and_Repositories

Answer (score 0):

regarding this issue

```
"dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin"
```

looks like you need to double check `/etc/sudoers` following entries are exactly as below

```
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
```

( To edit /etc/sudores you can use  `sudo visudo` )

Then also do the following

```
sudo cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
sudo mv ia32-libs-raring.list.disable ia32-libs-raring.list.BAK
sudo mv steam.list.disable steam.list.BAK
sudo mv ia32-libs-raring.list.disable ia32-libs-raring.list.BAK
sudo mv steam.list.disable steam.list.BAK
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I did the commands you ask very carefully. My /etc/sudoers entries were correct (they were exactly the same as you wrote). Then i did all the following command but i still have an error at the     sudo apt-get update

Comment: And I still can't do my update and install software with Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: What would be the error now? same error or different one ?